# Merge dictionary with dictionary map, and combine values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a nice way of updating a dictionary using a dictionary map, and combine their values?

For example:

```py
input = {"Puppy": 1, "Woof": 3, "Meow": 4, "Kitten": 6}

simplified_dict_map = {
    "Puppy" : "Dogs",
    "Woof" : "Dogs",
    "Meow" : "Cats",
    "Kitten" : "Cats",
}
```

Expected output:

```
result = {"Dogs": 4, "Cats": 10}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `defaultdict` goes a long say to simplifying this:

```
import collections
import json

data_in = {"Puppy": 1, "Woof": 3, "Meow": 4, "Kitten": 6}
simplified_dict_map = {"Puppy" : "Dogs", "Woof" : "Dogs", "Meow" : "Cats", "Kitten" : "Cats"}

results = collections.defaultdict(int)
for key, value in data_in.items():
    results[simplified_dict_map[key]] += value

print(json.dumps(results, indent=2))
```

Should give you:

```
{
  "Dogs": 4,
  "Cats": 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a for loop!

```py
result = {}
for key, value in simplified_dict_map.items():
    if key in input:
        if value not in result:
            result[value] = 0
        result[value] += input[key]

print(result) # {'Dogs': 4, 'Cats': 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in input.items():
    result[simplified_dict_map[key]] += value
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work :

```
keys = list(input.keys())
result = {}
for k in keys:
  if simplified_dict_map[k] in list(result.keys()):
    result[simplified_dict_map[k]]+=input[k]
  else:
    result[simplified_dict_map[k]]=input[k]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
solution = {}

for k1, v1 in input_dict.items():
    for k2, v2, in simplified_dict_map.items():
        if k1 == k2:
            if v2 in solution.keys():
                solution[v2] = solution[v2] + v1
            else:
                solution[v2] = v1
print(solution)
```